# How to update a variable in java from python using Jython

Tags: java, python, jython

I wanted to know how to update a variable in java from python.
I am using JYTHON Interpreter and executing the python script using JAVA.
For example:
sample.java has a variable named 'x'. Now I need to update a variable x from python script.

Can someone tell me how to do it?

Comment: You'd have to use a pipe or a text file.

Comment: Do you have some example code demonstrating the problem?

Comment: Hi Klaus,
Thanks for reply. Please find sample code as below

Comment: `public class Calculator {  private List<String> lstSts;  public Calculator(){  lstSts = new ArrayList<String>();  }  public void updateList(String sUpdate) {  lstSts.add(sUpdate);  }  }`

Comment: JavaInPython.py  
`import Calculator

class javaInPython(Calculator):
 def __init__(self):
  pass

def calculateTotal(self, cost, tip, tax):
 self.updateList("1")
 self.updateList("2")
 self.updateList("3")

if __name__ == "__main__":
 calc = javaInPython()
`

Comment: @ViswanathDuddu: please edit the question instead of adding code in comments.